# Show by using finite intersection property that( $\mathbb R$,d) is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I know that this problem is an application to the statement-

($\mathbb X$,d) is compact$\iff$Every collection of closed sets in ($\mathbb X$,d) with the finite intersection property  has a non-empty intersection.

A hint given in my text-"The set $F_n=\{x,x\ge n\}$ are closed and each finite family has non-empty intersection; yet $\cap_{i=0}^\infty F_n $=$\emptyset$".

My question is what is the significance of "$n$" here.

if possible, please explain me this in detail,as i'm a beginner in  topology

Thank you!

Comment: $n$ denotes natural numbers. So you have $F_1, F_2$, etc.

Comment: The intersection is $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty F_n$, not  $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty F_n$.